# Pass parameter in create table using batch file and SQLCMD

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, parameter-passing, sqlcmd

I have to pass a parameter (date) into a create table script that will be triggered via a batch file. I have used `SQLCMD` and the code is as follows

Batch

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/:." %%a in ("%TIME%") do (
       set hh=%%a&set nn=%%b&set ss=%%c&set ms=%%d)
echo "timeset"   
set V_TIMESTAMP=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%
echo %V_TIMESTAMP%

sqlcmd -E -S %V_SERVER% -d %V_DATABASE% -b -i %V_SQL_SCRIPT%  -v timestmp=%V_TIMESTAMP%
```

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblname_'($timestmp)'](
[PKCol1] [int] NOT NULL)
```

From what I see that output should a table with the name `tblname_20131022` but what I see is a table created with the name `tblname_'($timestmp)'`

Is there anything wrong in what I have done? Please suggest.

Thank you,
Vibhav

Comment: May be i'm wrong, but where are %yyyy% %mm% and %dd% defined/initialized ?

Comment: In the for loop. I pulled those values from the date variable.
set hh=%%a&set nn=%%b&set ss=%%c&set ms=%%d

Comment: No. You set %hh%, %nn%, %ss% and %ms% from %TIME% variable.

Answer (score 0):

In your CREATE TABLE statement, the dollar sign ($) needs to be outside the parentheses... and get rid of the quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblname_$(timestmp)](
[PKCol1] [int] NOT NULL)
```